# How to find Fourier coefficients and Fourier transformation of a Function

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, fourier-transform, numerical-calculus

I have the following problem:

I must Determine the real Fourier coefficients for the nodes $x_k = \frac{2πk}{4} , k ∈{0, 1, 2, 3}$ for the following function

$f(x) =
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 &-1  & 0 ≤ x < π\\ 
 & 1 & π ≤ x ≤ 2π 
\end{matrix}\right.
$

and give the corresponding Fourier transformatiomn $f_F:[0,2π]→R$ explicitly.

I really don't know how to find the Fourier coefficients.

Can someone help me? and from them how can I find the Fourier transformation?

Comment: where have you found this problem? Look up the definition of Fourier coefficient in a book

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSquareWave.html.